# how to forward to a new page on click a tab of tabview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I have a page named **Tabview1** which composed of tabview.

```
   Tabview1.xhtml:
       <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="1">
               <ui:include src="/Apanel.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="2">
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="3">
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

I want to forward to the page Tabview2.xhtml if click on the tab named **2**.

```
Tabview2.xhtml:
       <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="1">
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="2">
               <ui:include src="/Bpanel.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="3">
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabview creates a list with one element for each tab. Every `<li>` contains an `<a href="#j_idtXXX">`. Create a script on your site that changes these links to Tabview2.xhtml. For example if you set the id of your tabview to "tabview":

```
jQuery("#tabview ul a").first().attr("href", /MyPortal/Tabview2.jsf?tab=0);
```

This would cause the first tab to lead to the new page, and select the right tab on that page if you have configured a viewparam and have `activeIndex="#{controllerClass.activeIndex}"` set on the tabview.

I'm in a rush now, so I only had time to write a short example, but if you have some skill with javascript, it should not be too hard.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I am able to change the 'href' attribute in the 'a' elements contained in the li elements. But the click doesn't deliver the user to the new page. The default action must be overriden through JS to not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
               <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="Title1">
               <p:panel>  
                <ui:include src="tabView1.xhtml" />
               </p:panel>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Title 2">
                 <p:panel>  
                <ui:include src="tabView2.xhtml" />
                 </p:panel>
             </p:tab>           
        </p:tabView>
```